# Getting 400 Response Error Message in JS

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a dot net MVC controller that returns a 400 response with an error message when there's obviosuly a bad request, as seen below:

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "This is a bad request");
```

This controller is hit through the JQuery Post method

```
    $.post({
    url: window.location.href,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(payload),
    success: function (data) {
        window.location.href = data;
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $('.submit-calculate').html(jqXHR.responseText);
        debugger;
    }};
```

My issue is that the string I return when returning the `HttpStatusCodeResult` string property is inaccessible. The jqXHR has a property response text which contains a HTML page for a 400 response, which renders the following on the page:

[image]
Now the error message is display within this HTML but I want to just access that string (`"This is a bad request"`) without having to pull it out of that response. Not sure if there's a property that I can't see right now or I need to return something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `JsonResult` class to return JSON result

```
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
return new JsonResult(){
      Data = "This is a bad request"
};
```